# Welsh Language, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

I'm trying to insert the following Welsh special characters into a SQL Server database:

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/welsh.html

See the section Windows Alt Codes

I've attempted using an NVARCHAR and VARCHAR datatype, and the collation is set as SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

When I attempt to insert a character such as the W, after querying SQL Server strips the special character out and shows an unformatted W.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: If the string you send to the database isn't unicode, it makes no difference in what the table datatype is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using `nvarchar` not `varchar` and the `N` prefix before any string literals. e.g.

```
SELECT N'ŴẂẄẀ' /*(Returns `ŴẂẄẀ` for me)*/

SELECT 'ŴẂẄẀ' /*(Returns `W???` for me)*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the Unicode--that means Nchar or Nvarchar!

And in the query you can like this

```
N'ŵŴẂ'
```